# Show that $\sum_{k=1}^{p}{{p+1}\choose k}2^k=\sum_{k=1}^{p}{{p+1}\choose k}2^{p+1-k}$

Tags: summation, proof-writing, binomial-coefficients

> Show that $$\sum_{k=1}^{p}{{p+1}\choose k}2^k=\sum_{k=1}^{p}{{p+1}\choose k}2^{p+1-k}.$$

I know that the binomial coefficients are symmetric but how can I proof that the left and the right side are equal?

Comment: I don't know how to write it out explicitly.

Comment: Try and write out each sum without the Sigma notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $j=p+1-k$, which covers the same range of values as $k$. Since $\binom{p+1}{k}=\binom{p+1}{j}$, $\sum_k\binom{p+1}{k}2^k=\sum_j\binom{p+1}{j}2^{p+1-j}$.

Comment: which covers the same range of values as k … first of all why is this necessary and second how can I prove it?

Comment: @New2Math The map $k\mapsto p+1-k$ sends $1$ to $p$, $2$ to $p-1$ etc. down to sending $p$ to $1$. it's important so that $\sum_j f(j)=\sum_k f(k)$ allows us to rewrite my final expression as the one you wanted.

Comment: what do I have to understand to understand what you mean?

Comment: @New2Math All I can suggest is you work through the problem to understand what each step does.

Comment: My goal is to change the order of Summation formally. But there are a few Things I don't understand, I hope you can help: first of all if $\phi:\{1,...,p\}\rightarrow \{1,..,p\}$ is bijective then $\sum_{k=1}^{p}f(k)=\sum_{k=1}^{p}f(\phi(k))$, then there is another Thing I don't understand why the map you proposed $\phi:\{1,...,p\}\rightarrow\{1,...,p\},\phi(k)=p+1-k$ is bijective, i.e injective and surjective? Suppose I take that all for granted then I could say $\sum_{k=1}^{p}\binom{p+1}{k}2^k=\sum_{k=1}^{p}\binom{p+1}{\phi(k)}2^{\phi(k)}=\sum_{k=1}^{p}\binom{p+1}{p+1-k}2^{p+1-k}$

Comment: And also where is the Connection with the indexsubstitution?

Comment: @New2Math In fact $\phi$ as defined is an [involution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Involution_(mathematics)) on $\{1,\,\cdots,\,p\}$, ensuring it's both an injection and surjection.

Answer (score 2):

Hint. Note that
$${{p+1}\choose k}={{p+1}\choose p+1-k}$$
then change the summation's index and set $j=p+1-k$.

Comment: Okey I wrote $\sum_{k=1}^p\binom{p+1}{k}2^k=\sum_{k=1}^{p}\binom{p+1}{p+1-k}2^k$. Now what do you mean with changing the sumation index. $k$ has to be bounded- what is the next step?

Comment: If $j=p+1-k$ then $k=p+1-j$, the limits for $j$ are $p+1-1=p$ and $p+1-p=1$, and the sum becomes $\sum_{j=1}^p\binom{p+1}{j}2^{p+1-j}$

Answer (score 1):

Use the formula for the binomial sum

- $(a+b)^n =\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}a^kb^{n-k}$

and interchange the roles of $a$ and $b$ as follows:

$$(1+2)^{p+1}=1 + \sum_{k=1}^{p}{{p+1}\choose k}2^k +2^{p+1}= 2^{p+1} + \sum_{k=1}^{p}{{p+1}\choose k}2^{p+1-k} + 1 = (2+1)^{p+1}$$